# Spring Cloud Gateway not executing filter if the controller is in same project

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, JwtTokenValidationAndRouteFilter authenticationCheckAndRouteFilter, AuthServerFilter authServerFilter) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("auth-routes", r -> r.path("/myapp/api/v1/auth/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(authServerFilter)).uri("lb://auth-server"))
                .route("evoke-endpoints", r -> r.path("/myapp/services/v1/request")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(authenticationCheckAndRouteFilter)).uri("lb://cloud-gateway"))
             
                .build();
    }

}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JwtTokenValidationAndRouteFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        final List<String> apiEndpoints = Arrays.asList("/myapp/services/v1/request/**");
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isApiSecured = r -> apiEndpoints.stream().noneMatch(uri -> r.getURI().getPath().contains(uri));
        Claims claims = null;
        String errorMessage = null;

        if (isApiSecured.test(request)) {
            if (!request.getHeaders().containsKey("Authorization")) {
                errorMessage = "Authorization token not present in request headers, please check.";
                return onError(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, errorMessage, request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().toString());

            }
            final String token = request.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("Authorization").get(0);
            if (token == null || token.isEmpty() || !token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                errorMessage = "Authorization token should start with Bearer, please check.";
                return onError(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, errorMessage, request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().toString());

            }
            try {
                final String jwt = token.substring(7);
                JwtUtils.isTokenValid(jwt);
                claims = JwtUtils.extractAllClaims(jwt);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                log.error("ExpiredJwtException occurred.. please check..");
                errorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                log.error("MalformedJwtException occurred.. please check..");
                errorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                log.error("Unknown Exception occurred while validating the token..", e);
            }
            if (errorMessage != null && !errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                return onError(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, errorMessage, request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().toString());
            }
            exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("id", String.valueOf(claims.get("id"))).build();
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/services/v1/request"})
public class EvokeController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/handle-emk-request", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> processRequest(@RequestBody String request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(request);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/health", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkHealth() {
        return null;
    }
```

If I invoke http://localhost:8080/myapp/services/v1/request it is not executing my filter "JwtTokenValidationAndRouteFilter ". It is directly calling the endpoint and giving the response.

All these classes present in same project.

My app should execute the filter first then it has to call the controller.

tried to multiple ways and couldn't find anything.

Comment: If this `/myapp/services/v1/request` maps to a controller, then it will never hit the gateway. Do you want just a webflux `WebFilter`?

Comment: how can I make it do go via gateway?